# SQL Server 2012 Express Configuration and access

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012-express

I developed a program that uses a local database. Everything is ok when I install the program in the computer that I used to develop. But when I install it in another computer (I have to install SQL Server Express on that computer ), this message appears:

> A  network related or instance specific error occurred while establishing a ..... (provider:Named Pipes Provider, error:40 - Could not open  a connection to SQL server.

I already:

1. checked and ensure that TCP/IP and the Named Pipes are enabled.
2. already disabled the firewall.
3. added an exception to port 1433...     My connection string in my c# is

   ```
   Data Source=localhost; Initial Catalog = dbName ; Integrated Security=SSPI
   ```

This is the first time I need to do this, can anyone guide me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be several problems.  First, the firewall settings are irrelevant in this case, so ignore that and turn your firewall back on.

Check that the SQL Server Windows Service is running on the client machine.  It isn't always turned on by default after installing SQL Server Express.  Next, check the name of the SQL Server service.  Ensure that the connection string you have in the application is using the correct service name in the Data Source field.  Using localhost usually doesn't work.  Try using .\SQLEXPRESS or .\<>

If it's not either of these, you'll need to do a deeper dive by installing SSMS and trying to troubleshoot your connection string and connection.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add server instance in data source or use the port number like this:

```
Data Source=localhost,1433 or Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS
```